# Working with Span of Unmanaged memory on C# .NET do not work as expected in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, memory

I have a simple example for working with Unmanaged Memory (native Heap) with .Net Marshal Class As below.

```
const int nbytes = 100;
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nbytes);
    try
    {
        var ptrToInt = (int*)ptr.ToPointer();// We should cast void* to int*
        Span<int> span = new Span<int>(ptrToInt, nbytes >> 2);
        span.Fill(42);
        int cap = nbytes >> 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(span[i]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(",", string.Join(",", span.ToArray())); // This does not work and I do not know why?!
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);// We should free memory we used at the end
    }
```

The point here is that the method ToArray for span do not work while I traverse the span index by index it works well. What is the reason behind this? Spans for Managed Memory works well so I think there is something that I do not know/consider about the span here
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the warning on your code:

[image]

Solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(",", span.ToArray()));
```

Result:

[image]